# Как восстановить R.java?

Tags: android, java

После очистки android-проекта пропал R.java файл.Соответственно, запустить проект не могу...
Раз 20 делал очистку, файл не появляется.
Может кто подскажет, как восстановить его?

Answer (score 3):

1. Проверьте ошибки в хмл файлах разметки.
2. Ошибки в классах.
3. Запустите еще раз.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать новый проект с помощью импорта или просто скопировав весь код. По идее должно все получиться =)

Answer (score 0):

Самый верный способ это сгенерировать вручную через aapt:

```
$aapt package -m -J <SOURCE_FOLDER> -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res -I <SDK_PATH>/platforms/android-xx/android.jar
```

- **SOURCE_FOLDE**R - каталог с исходниками
- **SDK_PATH** - путь к SDK Android'а
- **xx** - номер API

А вообще скорее всего у вас ошибка в AndroidManifest.xml - проверьте еще раз

Answer (score 0):

R.java - это файл который генерируется автоматически, ничего руками вносить или изменять в нем не нужно. Если у Вас проект без ошибок просто обновите список папок и все. Если R.java не генерируется и у Вас весь проект в ошибках, смотрите в лог Console (это если в Eclipse работаете)там написано в каком файле ошибка. Исправьте её и R.java сам появится.